# Как аналогично сделать на jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть несколько прослушек на JS, как сделать аналогичное на JQuery?
Объясните, кто хорошо понимает: почему переменные *inp* и *nameFscrn* не равны? И как заменить `addEventListener` на аналогичное с JQuery?

```
var inp = document.getElementById('name-f-scrn');
var nameFscrn = $('#name-f-scrn');

inp.addEventListener('invalid', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  if (!event.target.validity.valid){
    $('.notify').addClass('error').text('Введите имя в одном из следующих форматов: Имя, Фамилия Имя, Фамилия Имя Отчество');
    nameFscrn.addClass('invalid');
  }
});

inp.addEventListener('input', function(event){
  if ($('.notify').css('display') == 'block'){
    nameFscrn.removeClass('invalid');
    $('.notify').removeClass('error');
  }
});
```

А также вот в следующем коде, как заменить строчку `document.getElementById('bcaa-f-scrn').checked` на аналогичную на JQuery?

```
$('#bcaa-f-scrn').change(function(){
  if(document.getElementById('bcaa-f-scrn').checked){
    bcaaVal = $('#bcaa-quantity').val() * 1;
    bcaaWeight = $('#bcaa-quantity option:selected').data('weight') * 1;
  }else{
    bcaaVal = 0;
    bcaaWeight = 0;
  }
});
```

Буду очень благодарен!

Comment: `document.getElementById('name-f-scrn') === $('#name-f-scrn')[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эти функции можно заменить с помощью `on`.

```
var inp = document.getElementById('name-f-scrn');
var nameFscrn = $('#name-f-scrn');

nameFscrn.on('invalid', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (!event.target.validity.valid) {
    $('.notify').addClass('error').text('Введите имя в одном из следующих форматов: Имя, Фамилия Имя, Фамилия Имя Отчество');
    nameFscrn.addClass('invalid');
  }
});

nameFscrn.on('input', function() {
  if($('.notify').css('display') == 'block') {
    nameFscrn.removeClass('invalid');
    $('.notify').removeClass('error');
  };
});
```

Выводит оно не одно и тоже потому, что `document.getElementById` выводит определённый элемент, а `$('#...')` выводит лист элементов с таким ID. Что бы к этой записи можно было применять функции JS, нужно указать индекс элемента: `$('#...')[индекс]` или `$('#...').get(индекс)`. Для ID, индекс всегда `0`

Все значения типа `checked` прописываются и проверяются через функцию `prop`:

```
$('#bcaa-f-scrn').change(function() {
  if ( $('#bcaa-f-scrn').prop('checked') ) {
    bcaaVal = $('#bcaa-quantity').val() * 1;
    bcaaWeight = $('#bcaa-quantity option:selected').data('weight') * 1;
  } else {
    bcaaVal = 0;
    bcaaWeight = 0;
  }
});
```

Comment: _"$('#...') выводит лист элементов с таким ID"_ - а я б поспорил)))

Comment: @Qwertiy, что не так?)) В консоле записал и оно вывело мне список, как при `querySelectorAll`

Comment: Ну с одной стороны так, а с другой - там один элемент. Если id уникален, то всё хорошо, а если нет, то упс))) https://jsfiddle.net/99m1js0z/1/ - В хроме `1 4 4`, а какой-то IE говорил `1 1 4`. Но первое везде 1.

Comment: @Qwertiy, тут да, но вот в ситуации с чистыми JS функциями ID обязателен https://jsfiddle.net/99m1js0z/2/

Comment: Во-первых, про выдирание элемента я и не спорил. Я процитировал конкретную фразу. Во-вторых, я вообще-то не согласен: раз уж мы подключили jQuery, то надо им и пользоваться, а не ковырять dom-элементы, чтобы у них вызывать нативные методы. По крайней мере для того, что покрывается самим jQuery.

Comment: @Qwertiy, не спорю =)

Comment: Кстати, кажется я ответ не дочитал))) Держи плюс за вторую часть :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, только за вторую? А первая не заслужила?)

Comment: А в первой мне лень сравнивать кусок кода с вопросом)))

Comment: @Qwertiy, я всего 2 строки сменил! :D

Comment: Но чтобы их определить, надо прочитать 12. Ну вот, мне стало интересно, какая вторая)))

Comment: ребята, а что значит this здесь: nameFscrn.on('invalid', this, ......
и как заменить вот это на аналогичное на jquery? if (!event.target.validity.valid)

Comment: @reFactorPro, по идее должен указывать на `nameFscrn`, но по моему указывает на `window`. В общем это вообще можно убрать :D

Comment: @reFactorPro, это и есть jQuery. Только вот `, this` надо выкинуть.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> document.getElementById('bcaa-f-scrn').checked
> ```

```
$('#bcaa-f-scrn').prop('checked')
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, пишите более развёрнутые ответы :) Ваш ответ попал в очередь проверок некачественных ответов

Comment: @Yuri, краткость - сестра таланта :) Что именно непонятно в этом ответе?

Comment: Лично мне, всё понятно. А вот если зайдёт первоклассник  и он ничего не поймёт, что это за код в жёлтой штучке, а под ним что за фигня? :D

Comment: исходя из вопроса, ответ понятен! Я очень благодарен за ответ

Comment: @reFactorPro, если вопрос решён, выбери один из ответов и прими его нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Comment: Что это за код в желтой штучке и снизу за фигня?

Comment: @vp_arth, вопрос и ответ. Или что? И вообще, что вы тут одинаковые комменты пишете?